# Prevent ajax from hanging .NET web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Basically I'm building a youtube contact management application not using the official youtube api, basically you login to youtube in the application and it'll redirect to http://www.youtube.com/address_book, the main issue is that when the user has say over 5000+ contacts then ajax on youtubes page begins to load all those users into view at once and it makes the web browser hang and thus resulting in the entire application freezing. Is there a way around it? Unfortunately login is required to be view the contacts otherwise I would just scrape the source without a web browser.

Comment: What does your code look like that does the loading.. perhaps you could refactor your code, but once again hard to tell / determine when one can not see your `SRC`

Comment: It's not really an issue with the code, even if I create a new project and just have a browser with "http://youtube.com/address_book" as the url it'll also hang after ajax starts loading those values :(

Comment: How is that happeneing?  AJAX should have the opposite effect (asynchronous). Need code.

Comment: `Nornitus` sounds like you are a bit mistaken and or are not familiar with how web / asych calls are handled

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://youtube.com/address_book");
        } All I have is this, after say 5 seconds the entire application hangs.

Comment: By the look of it, it has nothing to do with ajax...

Answer (score -3):

After running a testing, surprisingly webbrowser.navigate is not blocking.  So the question lacks details necessary to answer.  Here's a demo that shows basically what you have given so far.  The call is not blocking:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        br.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");

        MessageBox.Show("navigate called");//this fires immediately
    }


    static void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        //Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
        MessageBox.Show(wb.Text);

    }
```

Comment: I'm really confused about how this "Task.Start" works but I shall look into it, thanks.

Comment: @Nornitus - Updated with a demo that just fires off a thread.

Comment: 1) `Navigate` is *not* blocking 2) It's a UI control, so if you access it from a background thread you'll just get a cross thread exception.

Comment: Unfortunately this still hung.

Comment: @Nornitus - Considering the example here, nothing you have given so far would tell me why its hung.  Either give more sample code or (if the code is excessive), stick a breakpoint on `InitializeCompenent()` and step through debug until you hit the line of code that does not return.  Then give us that line (or more likely you will already have your answer).

Comment: As I've said... it's nothing to do with the code... the browser is hanging because of the web page, that's why I included the link.